# symfony sfDoctrineRoute model question

Tags: php, symfony1

I couldn't understand completely how does the sfDoctrineRoute class works

for example, i have the following route:

```
Comment:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    prefix_path: :username/comment
    module: comment
    model: Comment
```

now, in `executeNew()` method of `commentActions` class, this code:

```
$this->getRoute()->getObject()
```

will return the first Comment object in my database. of course i can manually create a `new Comment()` object, but then what's the benefit of using the `sfDoctrineRoute` class instead of `sfRoute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of executeNew, there is little/no benefit to using a doctrine route.

Consider instead the executeEdit method (update, delete and show are the same too).

A url could be like:

/comment/5/edit

(or in your case, /myusername/comment/5/edit)

$this->getRoute()->getObject() will then return comment 5 from the database - saving you the trouble of loading it (only a line or 2 of code, but still). And, a neat feature, if there is no comment 5 in the database, it automatically handles this and causes a 404 error - so you don't need to worry about that either.

Comment: Adding to the list of pros, if you decide to switch to a slug-based url, for example, you only need to change some route options, instead of changing code in all your actions.

Comment: Yea you right.. thanks alot! :) btw, is there a way to prevent it from picking any record from my db incase of executeNew?